# ANTLR: How to give precedence to parser rule alternative

Tags: parsing, nlp, compiler-construction, antlr, grammar

So I am working with an ANTLR grammar for parsing dates, and I want to be able to recognize not just individual date-units, but also *pairs* of date-units.

For the purposes of this question, I think it might be helpful to divide the kinds of questions I want to be able to recognize into 3 classes:

1. `What was the temperature in August 2019?` - Straightforward. Single date-unit (August 2019).
2. `Which was hotter between June 3rd 2019 and yesterday?` - Still straightforward. Two date-units (June 3, 2019 and yesterday).
3. `Between August 2018 and 2019, which was hotter?` - Tricky. The natural expectation of the user in this case would be to compare August 2018 and August 2019 (implicitly). To handle such cases, I want `2018 and 2019` to be parsed as a single `year_pair` rule and `August` to be parsed as a `month`.

I am currently handling only cases 1 and 2. Case 1 is handled in a straightforward way. Case 2 is handles by having a `date_unit AND date_unit` rule. But to handle Case 3 now, I also tried adding a `year AND year` rule, so that `2018 and 2019` is picked up as a `year_pair` much before, but due to the top-down nature of ANTLR, it still parses them into `August 2018` and `2019`.

How can I go about changing this such that it parses `August 2018 and 2019` into `August` and `2018 and 2019` instead (while also retaining the general `date_unit AND date_unit` rule?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your grammar?

Comment: That question title is pretty misleading. You should consider replacing it by something that matches your actual question.

Comment: Yeah, given the title I expected something else. I understand the phrasing though...

Comment: @MikeLischke Why do you think it's misleading? I do want to give one rule precedence over another.

Comment: "bottom up style parsing" implies an LR parser, which ANTLR does not generate: it generates LL parsers (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-ll-and-lr-parser/ ). At least, that is what I think Mike meant :)

Comment: My previous question still stands. If you add your grammar, perhaps someone can suggest a solution. It's a bit hard to comment/suggest without seeing your grammar.

Comment: Well, what I meant was that this hasn't to do with precedence at all. Precedence is a term mostly for mathematical expression to guide the evaluation. This is not what I see here. This question is about how to semantically interpret input (which date value belong together, what should be done if a date has not all necessary parts, re-use of information given in a different part of the input, that kind of thing).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add semantic to a syntax. From a language standpoint the implicit user expectation doesn't matter at all. The parser (as a syntax tool) can only determine if input conforms to a language and not if the input also matches semantic rules).

Instead you should use ANTLR4 to quantify your input and create the parse tree. Then in a second step do the semantic analysis where you can apply your special date rules (e.g. auto fill implicit date parts).

Comment: Yeah no, I am trying to influence just the syntax actually. This influencing being motivated by a semantic concern doesn't automatically make it a semantic problem, no?

Comment: I would say it does. The syntactic elements remain the same, regardless of the meaning you apply to them. A syntactic concern would be if you expect certain lexems to follow a strict order. But in this case you are above this simple syntactic part and try interpret what the user meant in an otherwise syntactically correct sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"Bottom-up" is a term that's synonymous for LR parsing for decades and has nothing to do with ANTLR nor the problem. It's the wrong term.

Mike's solution above is what most people would do because a `date_range` corresponds to just a `Tuple<date_unit, date_unit>`, and one would just be creating that type in the semantic analyzer. You want to describe a different range, something like `Tuple<month, Tuple<year, year>>` and other variations syntactically. Here is a grammar that does that. It produces the trees you are looking for, for all three of your examples.

```
grammar Dates;

MONTH : 'January' | 'February' | 'March' | 'April' | 'May' | 'June' | 'July' | 'August' | 'September' | 'October' | 'November' | 'December' ;
YESTERDAY : 'yesterday' ;
FIRST : 'First';
SECOND : 'Second';
THIRD : 'Third';
AND : 'and' ;
BETWEEN : 'between';
ORDINAL: [1-9][0-9]* ('rd' | 'th');
CARDINAL : [0-9]+ ;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

// NB: Note order here.
range
    : BETWEEN month year_group
    | BETWEEN date_unit AND date_unit
    ;

input: ( date_unit | range ) EOF ;
year_group : year AND year ;
date_unit : month day year | month year | year | yesterday ;
day : ordinal | CARDINAL ;
ordinal : ORDINAL | FIRST | SECOND | THIRD ;
month : MONTH ;
year : CARDINAL ;
yesterday : YESTERDAY ;
```